# What is the difference between 'must-revalidate' and 'proxy-revalidate'?

Tags: http, cache-control

In my understanding, both of the two directives mean the cache server will ask the original server to revalidate the request from the client browser. What is the difference between these two directives?

Answer (score 8):

[RFC 7234, section 5.2.2.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.7), explains:

> The "proxy-revalidate" response directive has the same meaning as the
> must-revalidate response directive, **except that it does not apply to
> private caches.**

(Emphasis added.)  [An earlier version of the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4) went on to describe how that might be used:

> It can be used on a response to an authenticated request to permit the user's cache to store and later return the response without needing to revalidate it (since it has already been authenticated once by that user), while still requiring proxies that service many users to revalidate each time (in order to make sure that each user has been authenticated). Note that such authenticated responses also need the public cache control directive in order to allow them to be cached at all.